# WC_Order->get_items() not populating `tax_class` field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

In Woocommerce, `var_dumping` an order shows an empty field `tax_class`, but tax classes are defined and assigned correctly to the product.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
array(13) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Nuovo prodotto"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "line_item"
  ["item_meta"]=> ...
  ["item_meta_array"]=> ...
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["tax_class"]=>
  string(0) "" <-- this shouldn't be empty
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(2) "54"
  ["variation_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["line_subtotal"]=>
  string(6) "5.8824"
  ["line_total"]=>
  string(6) "5.8824"
  ["line_subtotal_tax"]=>
  string(6) "1.2941"
  ["line_tax"]=>
  string(6) "1.2941"
  ["line_tax_data"]=> ...
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: **This is normal** when tax class value is default for a product: If you have a look in your database in **postmeta** table at `_tax_class` **meta_key**, the corresponding **meta_value** is **empty**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is that is completely normal**

Because for a product, when **tax class value** is set on **default** the corresponding data stored in the database is `'meta_key' = '_tax_class'` => `'meta_value' = ''`. **So the value is empty**.